# Python: Why does the id(list) change when -: list = list + [value] is applied and not += [value]

Tags: python, list

I have been doing a study on the concept of ***Everything is an object in Python***, specially *Aliasing*. Then I stumbled upon these differences.

In my little knowledge of programming, I have seen in multiple languages like C, Javascript, Php, C++, even Python, that

```
number = 5
number = number + 1
```

This can be written as:

```
number += 1
```

Although, in python, I have been made to understand that this creates a new reference to another object, since integers are immutable.

But, here is the dispute when it comes with **lists in python**.

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
 print("a:  ", id(a))
 print(a)

 a += [4]
 print("a += [4]: ",  id(a))
 print(a)

 print()

 a = [1, 2, 3]
 print("a:  " , id(a))
 print(a)

 a = a + [4]
 print("a = a + [4]: " , id(a))
 print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
a:   508895715968
[1, 2, 3]
a += [4]:  508895715968
[1, 2, 3, 4]

a:   508895902976
[1, 2, 3]
a = a + [4]:  508895674816
[1, 2, 3, 4]

[Program finished]
```

**Why does id(a) after a += [4] differ from a = a + [4]?**

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the classic Python newbie surprises. `+=` isn't actually the same as combining `+` and `=`.

Comment: But it appears the same for numbers? @user2357112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Python program is run, the source code is compiled into bytecode instructions which are then executed by the python virtual machine.

To see the difference, we can use the `dis` module to check the bytecode generated in both cases:

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: a = [1, 2, 3]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: dis.dis("a += [4]")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              4 BUILD_LIST               1
              6 INPLACE_ADD
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

In [4]: dis.dis("a = a + [4]")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              4 BUILD_LIST               1
              6 BINARY_ADD
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the only difference in the generated bytecode is that `INPLACE_ADD` (the name speaks for itself) is used for `a += [4]`, while `BINARY_ADD` (which produces a new list) is used for `a = a + [4]`

Comment: `INPLACE_ADD` does not necessarily mean that the operation is in-place; it's simply a byte code that indicates that the appropriate type's `__iadd__` method will be used. It's `list.__iadd__` that does an in-place extension of the list, not the byte code itself. (Byte code is an implementation detail of CPython anyway; Python guarantees that `x += y` represents `x = x.__iadd__(y)` where `x.__iadd__` is implemented.)